# How to moq a class with Get() and Set() methods

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, stub

I can't seem to moq my class that has getter and setter methods (not properties). I need to save the variable somewhere to return it later on.

Signature of my class:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    int Get();
    void Set(int i);
}
```

My real implementation :

- Set() => Encrypts the int and saves it in a local variable
- Get() => Decrypts the int from local variable and returns int

How I want the moq to behave :

```
public class MyClassFake : IMyClass
{
    private int _local;
    public int Get()
    {
        return _local;
    }

    public void Set(int i)
    {
        _local = i;
    }
}
```

What I've tried and didn't work so far :

```
        var mockMyClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
        var number = new int();
        mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.Set(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<int>(x=> number = x);
        mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(number);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `Get()` setup to use the overload that receives a `Func<>` as parameter:

```
var mockMyClass = new Mock<IMyClass>();
var number = 0;
mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.Set(It.IsAny<int>())).Callback<int>(x => number = x);
mockMyClass.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(() => number);
```

In your current code, you are defining `Get()` result as a fixed number (initial value of `number`)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've googled it but unfortunately I'm still not sure how to overload my Get() method that recieves Func<> parameter. Would you provide an example?

Comment: @U.Bulle: Sorry, I means to the `Returns()` call: `Returns(() => number);`

Comment: I was a bit scared of overloading the real class, but it wasn't even needed and `() =>` did the trick. Have a nice weekend Arturo, cheers ! :)